# upgrade from jackson(codehaus) 1.9 to jackson(fasterxml) 2.3

Tags: jackson, fasterxml

I have been facing a issue related to upgrading a opensource application from jackson 1.9 to jackson 2.3.

The problem is coming in the method objectmapper.readvalue. 
The version i was using initially was objectmapper.readvalue(jsonnode,typereference) with a jsondeserializer registered along with simplemodule.

now this method is deprecated in jackson2.3 and for this i planned to use 
objectmapper.readvalue(jsonparser,typereference) getting jsonparser through jsonnode.traverse().

But jsonparser passed through this way resulted in giving out a null objectmapper through jsonparser.getCodec(), which is a standard way of getting a result.

This code was totally working with jackson 1.9..

I am not very well versed with jackson and not been able to find ample document on net for migration to new jackson.

Looking forward for any pointer/help in this regard...

Thanks in advance